# Unable to set time zone in Windows 11

Tags: date-time, time-zone, windows-11-v22h2

So, I'm running into what seems to be a common problem, but I can't believe the answers I have found so far are the only right ones.

I'm running Windows 11 home, logged in as the administrator account.  I'm unable to change the time zone using either the regular date and time settings, or the old date and time box (I've attached screen shots of both so you can see what I'm talking about.  One is just grayed out, and the other tells me I don't have permission.

The two typical fixes seems to be to use tzutil in a command prompt (which does work), or enable location settings.  If I'm trying to set the time zone manually, I don't see why I have to enable locations services to do that.  I feel like there has to be a way to be able to do it in the typical date and time settings, without enabling location services.  Anyone have any suggestions that don't involve tzutil or enabling location?

One of the settings windows:
[image: One of the settings windows]

Other settings window:
[image: Other settings window]

Basically, other then turning on locations services, how can I make it so I can set my time zone from within the settings window?  I'd like to think Microsoft wouldn't make that a requirement, but it seems they have.

Comment: Are you the administrator user? Is this a home computer or a company computer? If company computer then it's likely to be on a domain that controls the time settings. If yes, then you should contact your IT dept. otherwise if no, then you should log in as the administrator account to change date/time settings.